# Convergence of Optimal Solutions

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

Suppose $Y_n$ is a sequence of random variables that converges to 1 in probability. Under what conditions the solution to the problem $\max_xE[f(xY_n)]$ converges to the solution to the problem $\max_xf(x)$? Assume all variables and function values are in one-dimensional Euclidean space. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the context of this problem?  What is the interval over which the function is maximized? Assuming $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, are you interested in  $\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$?  $\max_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)$? Perhaps this should really be $\sup$ to ensure well defined-ness?

Comment: Sure, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and the support of $Y_n$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $Y_n\neq 0$ then $\{xY_n : x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \mathbb{R}$.  So you are searching for a maximum (or supremum) of the function $f(\cdot)$ over the same set.  For example for any function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we have $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h(x) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h(2x) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h(-72.5x)$$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add expectation.